# pydev interactive console always disappearing and other console questions

Tags: python, eclipse, console, pydev

I've just started using pydev in Eclipse and I have a lot of questions about the way the interactive console works.

I have found out how to launch an interactive console and use it to run functions. My questions are this:

1. Every time I change my code and re-run it, my interactive console disappears. This is annoying as I have to reopen a console and I can't see/rerun my previous history. If I pin it, it stays, but then I can't run any code. Is there any way to keep the interactive console open all the time, but also be able to run your code? I currently spend a significant amount of my day closing and opening consoles!
2. How can I run a function from the interactive console, but still get the debugger to stop at breakpoints. I can use the debugger if I am running the code from a main function, but if I run the code from the console, it just skips right over break points.

thanks
Niall

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of clicking in "Python Run", you may press Ctrl+Alt+Enter with the desired Python file active, and the console will call `execfile` on it. All your previous story stays there. You can also select some part of your code and run only it.
2. As far as I know, you can't. Check the pdb module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the source of the problem is the same, but I encountered a similar issue in which the PyDev console kept disappearing as soon as I clicked in the script editor, even if the console's `Pin Console` button was clicked.

I solved this simply by **double-clicking on the script's tab**, which allowed the console to stay visible at all times.